# grub-efi-amd64 post install script error 255

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I installed a package this morning, which succeeded just fine, but I noticed an error related to grub-efi-amd64. I asked dpkg to configure the package to demonstrate the error. The post install script returns error 255.

I'm wondering if this is fallout from the boothole patch, but see I have a current version as the post boothole patched fixed version as supposed to be 2.02-2ubuntu8.16 and I have 8.17.
I'm on 18.04 with auto-updates enabled.

Suggestions?

```
05:38:51 [lana@Lana2018 ~]sudo dpkg --configure grub-efi-amd64
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.17) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64
```